# How to convert char* to unsigned short in C++

Tags: c++, c, pointers, casting, char

I have a `char* name` which is a string representation of the short I want, such as "15" and need to output this as `unsigned short unitId` to a binary file. This cast must also be cross-platform compatible.

Is this the correct cast: `unitId = unsigned short(temp);`

Please note that I am at an beginner level in understanding binary.

Comment: Why do you want to store the value of the pointer in a file in the first place?  Are you trying to use the pointer to the character string as some type of UID similar to a primary key in a database?  More details would be helpful.

Comment: I read a binary file and parse it, I then convert the data and output it to a new binary format. I am also working with legacy code. I really just need to learn how to convert char* to unsigned short.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I assume that your `char* name` contains a *string* representation of the short that you want, i.e. `"15"`.

Do *not* cast a `char*` directly to a non-pointer type. Casts in C don't actually change the data at all (with a few exceptions)--they just inform the compiler that you want to treat one type into another type. If you cast a `char*` to an `unsigned short`, you'll be taking the value of the *pointer* (which has nothing to do with the contents), chopping off everything that doesn't fit into a `short`, and then throwing away the rest. This is absolutely not what you want.

Instead use the [`std::strtoul`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul) function, which parses a string and gives you back the equivalent number:

```
unsigned short number = (unsigned short) strtoul(name, NULL, 0);
```

(You still need to use a cast, because `strtoul` returns an `unsigned long`. This cast is between two different integer types, however, and so is valid. The worst that can happen is that the number inside `name` is too big to fit into a `short`--a situation that you can check for elsewhere.)

Comment: well, you have to check it _before_ assigning to `number` for instance by assigning to an unsigned long first and check against `USHRT_MAX`.

Answer (score 9):

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

unitId = boost::lexical_cast<unsigned short>(temp);
```

Answer (score 6):

To convert a string to binary in C++ you can use stringstream.

```
#include <sstream>

. . .

int somefunction()
{
    unsigned short num;
    char *name = "123";
    std::stringstream ss(name);

    ss >> num;

    if (ss.fail() == false)
    {
        // You can write out the binary value of num.  Since you mention
        // cross platform in your question, be sure to enforce a byte order.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

that cast will give you (a truncated) integer version of the pointer, assuming temp is also a char*. This is almost certainly not what you want (and the syntax is wrong too).
Take a look at the function atoi, it may be what you need, e.g. unitId = (unsigned short)(atoi(temp));
Note that this assumes that (a) temp is pointing to a string of digits and (b) the digits represent a number that can fit into an unsigned short

Answer (score 0):

Is the *pointer* `name` the id, or the string of chars pointed to by `name`?  That is if `name` contains `"1234"`, do you need to output `1234` to the file?  I will assume this is the case, since the other case, which you would do with `unitId = unsigned short(name)`, is certainly wrong.

What you want then is the `strtoul()` function.

```
char * endp
unitId = (unsigned short)strtoul(name, &endp, 0);
if (endp == name) {
     /* The conversion failed. The string pointed to by name does not look like a number. */
}
```

Be careful about writing binary values to a file; the result of doing the obvious thing may work now but will likely not be portable.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string (char* in C) representation of a number you must use the appropriate function to convert that string to the numeric value it represents.

There are several functions for doing this. They are documented here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib